# What's the difference between gen and egen in Stata 12?

Tags: stata

Is there a reason why there are two different commands to generate a new variable?

Is there a simple way to remember when to use `gen` and when to use `egen`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They both create a new variable, but work with different sets of functions. You will typically use `gen` when you have simple transformations of other variables in your dataset like

```
gen newvar = oldvar1^2 * oldvar2
```

In my workflow, `egen` usually appears when I need functions that work across all observations, like in

```
egen max_var = max(var)
```

or more complex instructions

```
egen newvar = rowmax(oldvar1 oldvar2)
```

to calculate the maximum for each observation between `oldvar1` and `oldvar2`. I don't think there is a clear logic for separating the two commands.

Comment: There's a pretty clear logic, actually. If the task can be done with the existing mathematical functions, you use `generate`. If this is something more complicated, e.g. needs to be done on groups of observations (which are not very easily addressed in Stata), you would need to look for an appropriate `egen` function.

Comment: Agree. But I still don't see the logic of having two separate commands.

Comment: I think Stata's logic is very clear: `egen` is used whenever `gen` isn't :)

Comment: @griverorz, there are differences in implementation. `generate` is a fast internal command. `egen` is being parsed by Stata, and you can write extensions to it using Stata ado-code. You cannot do that with `generate`. This is a rather painful legacy of the 80s as compared to R where you can define a function inline and forget it after it was used.

Comment: StasK is correct. Techincally, `egen` is an "extension" to the `egen` command because it reaches beyond simple computations (`var1 + var2`, `log(var1)`, etc.) to add descriptive stats, standardizations and more. Some of the stuff that can be done with `plyr` and `apply` in R is therefore done with `statsby` and `egen` in Stata. I use it to gently hack confidence intervals and scatterplots.

Comment: So is it about backwards compatibility? egen functions not breaking or being ambiguous with gen functions?

Answer (score 4):

### `gen`

`generate` may be abbreviated by `gen` or even `g` and can be used with the following mathematical operators and functions:

- `+` addition
- `-` subtraction
- `*` multiplication
- `/` division
- `^` power

A large number of functions is available. Here are some examples:

- `abs(x)` absolute value of x
- `exp(x)` antilog of x
- `int(x) or trunc(x)` truncation to integer value
- `ln(x), log(x)` natural logarithm of x
- `round(x)` rounds to the nearest integer of x
- `round(x,y)` x rounded in units of y (i.e., round(x,.1) rounds to one decimal place)
- `sqrt(x)`square root of x
- `runiform()` returns uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and nearly 1
- `rnormal()` returns numbers that follow a standard normal distribution
- `rnormal(x,y)` returns numbers that follow a normal distribution with a mean of x and a s.d. of y

### `egen`

A number of more complex possibilities have been implemented in the `egen` command like in the following examples:

- `egen nkids = anycount(pers1 pers2 pers3 pers4 pers5), value(1)`
- `egen v323r = rank(v323)`
- `egen myindex = rowmean(var15 var17 var18 var20 var23)`
- `egen nmiss = rowmiss(x1-x10 var15-var23)`
- `egen nmiss = rowtotal(x1-x10 var15-var23)`
- `egen incomst = std(income)`
- `bysort v3: egen mincome = mean(income)`

Detailed usage explanations can be found at this [link](http://wlm.userweb.mwn.de/Stata/wstatgen.htm).